# Oracle unpivot while adding dates

Tags: sql, oracle12c, unpivot

I have these two tables linked by a simple key, one contains the project name and its start date and the other the planning, which look something like this:

```
projects
ID      NAME  START_DATE
1       foo   01/01/2017
2       barr  01/02/2017

planning
PRJ    M0    M1    M2
1      70    75    80
2      50    60    70
```

Could someone help me to join these two tables in order to produce:

```
PRJ    DATE        PLAN
1      01/01/2017  70
1      01/02/2017  75
1      01/03/2017  80
2      01/02/2017  50
2      01/03/2017  60
2      01/04/2017  70
```

`unpivot` seems to be useful here, but I haven't got much practice with it.

thanks

Comment: So - are the dates in format mm/dd/yyyy (and in the output you add one day each time), or are they dd/mm/yyyy and you add one MONTH each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider running an `UNPIVOT` in a CTE. Then, in main query calculate a row number to which can be used to add days to *START_DATE*.

Also, consider not storing data in a wide format with `M*` columns but long format of original value and indicator columns. Otherwise queries like below will be complex.

```
WITH master AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM planning
   UNPIVOT ("PLAN" FOR M_COLS IN (M0, M1, M2))  -- BUILD OUT LIST IN APP CODE
  )

SELECT m.PRJ, p.START_DATE + m.row_num AS m."DATE", m."PLAN"
FROM projects p
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT PRJ, "PLAN", ROW_NUMBER() 
                        OVER (PARTITION BY PRJ ORDER BY PRJ) - 1 AS row_num
    FROM master) AS m
ON p.ID = m.PRJ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually 120 columns to do that (from a total of about 150). but yeah, I could write a big union.  Also, this is the data I've got :( couldn't change it ..

Comment: See update. Even with `UNPIVOT` you must name all 120 columns in its `IN` clause. Consider application layer code (Python, Java, PHP) to build this `IN` list.

Answer (score 0):

When you unpivot, the column that keeps track of unpivoted columns can be of any data type. In this case, you can make it a `NUMBER` column, and you can assign values `0, 1, 2, ...` to columns `M0, M1, M2, ...` - so you can use that directly to adjust the start dates. See the `IN` list of the `UNPIVOT` clause.

```
with
  projects ( id, name, start_date ) as (
    select 1, 'foo', to_date('01/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 2, 'bar', to_date('01/02/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
  ),
  planning ( prj, m0, m1, m2 ) as (
    select 1, 70, 75, 80 from dual union all
    select 2, 50, 60, 70 from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select x.prj, p.start_date + x.col_num as start_date, x.plan
from   projects p
       join
       ( select prj, col_num, plan
         from   planning
         unpivot ( plan for col_num in (m0 as 0, m1 as 1, m2 as 2) )
       ) x
             on p.id = x.prj
order by prj, start_date      -- If needed.
;

       PRJ START_DATE       PLAN
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 01/01/2017         70
         1 01/02/2017         75
         1 01/03/2017         80
         2 01/02/2017         50
         2 01/03/2017         60
         2 01/04/2017         70
```